# Does @font-face work in all browsers?

Tags: html, css, font-face

Does @font-face work in all browsers ?

How can i use @font-face?

Comment: No; doesn't work at all in lynx.

Comment: @Wooble That's a text based browser. @Faressoft Don't worry about writing code for browsers that old.

Comment: There was a new dev release of Lynx last year, so I wouldn't say it was "that old".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check out: [@font-face browser support](http://webfonts.info/wiki/index.php?title=@font-face_browser_support)

Webkit/Safari

- since version 3.1
- font formats:

  - TrueType/OpenType TT (.ttf)
  - OpenType PS (.otf)
  - SafariMobile (iPhone/iPad): only SVG Fonts
- More info: http://webkit.org/blog/124/downloadable-fonts/
- Wiki: Code samples

Opera

- since
  Opera 10: http://www.opera.com/browser/ and Opera Mobile 9.7
- font formats:

  - TrueType/OpenType TT (.ttf)
  - OpenType PS (.otf)
  - SVG (.svg)
- More info: http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/seven-web-fonts-showcases/

Internet Explorer

- since IE 4
- font formats:

  - Embedded OpenType (EOT) created by Microsoft's WEFT tool
  - WOFF since IE9
- More info: http://www.microsoft.com/typography/web/embedding/default.aspx
- Wiki: Code samples

Mozilla/Firefox

- since Firefox 3.5
- font formats

  - TrueType/OpenType TT (.ttf)
  - OpenType PS (.otf)
  - WOFF (since Firefox 3.6)
- Wiki: Code samples

Google Chrome

- In Chrome 4.0 stable release. As of January 25th, 2010
- In Chrome 3.0, you could run the executable with a command line switch of: --enable-remote-fonts [1](http://webfonts.info/wiki/index.php?title=@font-face_browser_support)
- It was disabled by default for security review: [2](http://craigmod.com/journal/font-face/) [3], [4]
- More details on chrome and @font-face here
- font formats

  - TrueType/OpenType TT (.ttf)
  - OpenType PS (.otf)
  - WOFF since version 6

Netscape

- since version 4, discontinued since Netscape Navigator 6
- font formats:

  - Portable Font Resource (.pfr)
- more info: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TrueDoc

**As for usage, check this out:**

- [The Potential of Web Typography:](http://craigmod.com/journal/font-face/)

Comment: One may want to mention that @font-face in Opera is almost unusable. See http://readableweb.com/font-face-in-opera-10-5-pre-alpha-stinks-despite-snapshot-hype/ or http://readableweb.com/opera-admits-font-face-bugs-in-opera-10/ I also experienced other bugs, where two different fonts were mingled together before stopping using @font-face in Opera altogether. I don't know if support got any better in release 11.

Answer (score 1):

Not all browsers but all of the big ones (Chrome, IE, FireFox, Opera, Safari). Sarfraz's post shows which it will work with.

Here's an example of how to use it:

```
@font-face {
font-family: DeliciousRoman;
src: url(/Delicious-Roman.otf);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommoned you use http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator to create the fonts and the css for you to use.

It will work in all browsers instantly. I tried fixing it myself, but there are some annoying differences to handle. Also getting it too work on Android browser AND IE8 and lower was difficult.

Using the website above, you will get it working quickly without any javascript or other hacks.

Answer (score 0):

You can always ask: http://caniuse.com/#search=font-face